# Not able to determine current orientation of device

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a problem that `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` returns 0 in some cases. In my understanding this should never happen.

It's not even at startup. Do I now have to create my own instance variable that keeps track of every rotation and stores it?

Comment: This happens when you haven't enabled device orientation notifications with `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`. You can check the `generatesDeviceOrientationNotifications` property to see if this is enabled when `orientation` returns `0`. Perhaps your calls to `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotification` aren't properly balanced?

Comment: If you can read what is written on it, then it's up. If that looks really strange, it's upside down :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and then came across this article:

[Don't Rely On UIDevice Orientation For Rotation](http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/08/23/dont-rely-on-uidevice-orientation-for-rotation/)

I hope that helps.